# Cisco APIC: How to get "Security Policies - Filters" via CLI?

Tags: cisco

GUI

```
APIC > Tenant > common > Security Policies > Filters
```

[image]

I've been trying various commands to get this output via CLI/SSH but didn't work so far.

```
ACI# show running-config all | grep -nC 3 Filters
ACI#
```

I also tried to grep `Filters` from `sh run` but did not get anything.

What is the right command to get "Security Policies - Filters" via CLI/SSH?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From APIC CLI execute next command:

```
moquery -c vzFilter -x 'query-target-filter=wcard(vzFilter.dn,"TENANT")'
```

where **TENANT** is your tenant name. You can also omit whole **-x** construction to display filters from all tenants in a fabric.

To get filter rules (proto/ports/etc):

```
moquery -c vzFilter -x 'query-target-filter=wcard(vzFilter.dn,"TENANT")' 'query-target=children' 'target-subtree-class=vzEntry'
```

But in this case you will see each filter rule separately. You can add more query filters to select exact filter name to see all rules that inside it.

Comment: Ok, there is also one addition about filter contents. Give me few minutes to figure out query for it.